# Calculating the limit of the sum

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I would like to receive some help with the next problem:

I'm trying to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, but i don't know if i can use it in this problem, because i don't think i can put limes in sum, like you can do with roots or integrals.

I'm apologizing, but I'm stuck at the beginning.

Please, could you give me some hints about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with the function $e^x$?

Comment: in particular, the series for $e^x$ ?

Comment: @Michael Biro: Yes. I'm trying to develop a function $f(x) = e^x$ into the power series and  this is the last part. I want to calculate the sum of the series in order to prove that it is equal to the value of the $f$ in $x = 0$. Maybe, i'm doing everything wrong.

Comment: @OgnjenMojovic That's not wrong, but it would depend on what definition you're using for $e^x$.

Comment: @MichaelBiro : In the text of the problem, it's $f(x) = e^x$. I know that $e$ is defined as the limit $\lim_{n \to infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$, but curently, i can't see how that would help me.

Comment: @OgnjenMojovic Ok, with that definition, try expanding $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{nx}$ out using the binomial theorem, and match terms in the limit to $\sum \frac{x^k}{k!}$.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$, note it solves $y^\prime=y,\,y(0)=1$ so the series is $e^x$. Your original strategy would never work because it only tells you the terms $\to 0$, which is true in any convergent series.